# Kafka Stream producing custom list of messages based on certain conditions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We have the following stream processing requirement.

```
Source Stream -> 
 transform(condition check - If (true) then generate MULTIPLE ADDITIONAL messages else just transform the incoming message) ->
 output kafka topic

Example:
If condition is true for message B(D,E,F are the additional messages produced)
A,B,C -> A,D,E,F,C -> Sink Kafka Topic
If condition is false     
A,B,C -> A,B,C -> Sink Kafka Topic
```

Is there a way we can achieve this in Kafka streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap()` or `flatMapValues()` methods. These methods take one record and produce zero, one or more records.

`flatMap()` can modify the key, values and their datatypes while `flatMapValues()` retains the original keys and change the value and value data type.

Here is an example pseudocode considering the new messages "C","D","E" will have a new key.

```
KStream<byte[], String> inputStream = builder.stream("inputTopic");
KStream<byte[], String> outStream = inputStream.flatMap( 
           (key,value)->{
            List<KeyValue<byte[], String>> result = new LinkedList<>();  
                // If message value is "B". Otherwise place your condition based on data     
                if(value.equalsTo("B")){ 
                      result.add(KeyValue.pair("<new key for message C>","C"));
                      result.add(KeyValue.pair("<new key for message D>","D"));
                      result.add(KeyValue.pair("<new key for message E>","E"));

                 }else{
                         result.add(KeyValue.pair(key,value));
                 }
            return result;
});
outStream.to("sinkTopic");
```

You can read more about this : 
https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#streams-developer-guide-dsl-transformations-stateless

Comment: What if we want to produce conditionally ? Say I did some transformation and basis of the result  of the transformation, I want to decide whether to push to another topic or not ?